# Navigationbar does not animate when using translucent barstyle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

This does not work

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

when I have this barstyle

```
rootNavigationController.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

Is it any reason why it shouldn't animate away? Are there any fixes to this?

**EDIT**

This is NOT working:

```
[rootNavigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
[rootNavigationController.navigationBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

Comment: Have you made sure that self.navigationController is not nil? As in does the bar disappear at all?

Comment: It's actually working for me, although I first swapped the color of the navbar, and I later called (using `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`) to a method that calls the hide method. I noticed that when doing everything in one function, it tends to animate wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

The UIBarStyleBlackTranslucent is deprecated. Use UIBarStyleBlack and set the translucent property to YES instead.